# Ubuntu Server 12.04 Name Resolution

Tags: networking

I just installed ubuntu server 12.04 and for my surprise network configuration has changed.

Basically, by default the /etc/network/interfaces has a dynamic ip address:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

With such a configuration I can ping any internet site...

However, when I changed it to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address         192.168.0.120
    netmask         255.255.255.0
    gateway         192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Things just stop work!!! I've read the manual page hundred times to see what a hell I'm doing wrong and I just could not found what!!!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the range your DHCP server (probably on your router?) is assigned to use. Then use a static IP outside of that range for your server. e.g. if DHCP range is from 192.168.0.1 through 192.168.0.100, use something like 192.168.0.101

Answer (score 0):

I need some additional information.  Forgive me for asking the obvious, but have you restarted the server? If not, please do so and retest.

First, can you ping your gateway IP address? Type `ping 192.168.0.1` and press enter.

Another area to test, type `ifconfig` and press enter. Do you see eth0 listed with the inet addr of 192.168.0.120? Do you see any other interface listed in the left column other than eth0 and lo?

Also, we need to rule out that this is a DNS issue. At the terminal type `dig | grep SERVER` and press enter. You should see 192.168.0.1 in the line returned. If that is the case, type `dig google.com` and press enter. This should return a list of google's IP addresses. You also might want to consider adding these lines to your /etc/network/interfaces file:

network 192.168.0.0
 
broadcast 192.168.0.255

Then restart the server and retest.

What type of environment is the server running in? I am assuming this might be a home network with a router. When the server is running correctly from the dynamic IP address, what is the information returned by ifconfig? Answering these questions will be helpful and will provide me with a better starting point.

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing as in your last pargraph. It is possible that the router uses a different network e.g. 10.0.0.0 and thus the new settings do not work. Actually `ping localhost` should, but that's a different story.